# There are 173 dex generated when I packaged a debug apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

Here I have encountered a strange problem. When I packaged a debug APK file, there are 173 or more dex files generated like below:

[image]

It's always crash When I open the app on my phone. The message noted that

```
The main application can not find in any dex files
```

So I though the  main application (like xxxApplication.class ) class is not be setup. May be it matters with the 173 dexes.

I want to know why it is happens? Here is part of my app build file:

[image]

My buildToolVersion & compileSdkVersion is 25.
The android-build-tools version  is 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer about number of dex files. It is a way to provide Instant Run feature while you are being developing your application.

I found out about it in Google I/O 2017: [What's New in Android Development Tools (Google I/O '17)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hx_rwS1NTiI)

Also there is an article which describes hot / warm / cold swaps in details: [Instant Run: How Does it Work?!](https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f) which states:

> Android Studio monitors which files are changed during development, and runs a custom Gradle task to generate .dex files for only the modified classes.
>   Those new .dex files are picked up by Android Studio, which deploys it to the App Server

The way to achieve Instant Run is to substitute certain parts of you application dynamically.

If there are some Google employees here, please correct me.